# Weird template specification

Tags: c++, templates

I have run into this function signature

```
template<typename T>
template<typename FI>
void vector<T>::_M_assign_aux (FI first, FI last,std::forward_iterator_tag)
{}
```

Is it equivalent to this one?

```
template<typename T, typename FI>
void vector<T>::_M_assign_aux (FI first, FI last,std::forward_iterator_tag)
{}
```

Is there any reason to write it separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_M_assign_aux` looks like a method of `vector<T>`, so this should have started with a code like this:

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    // ...

    template<typename FI>
    void _M_assign_aux(FI first, FI last,std::forward_iterator_tag);

    // ...
};
```

Looking class declaration, the explanation is more "visible": you have one template declaration for the class, and one for the method.

```
template<typename T> // template declaration for vector
template<typename FI> // template declaration for _M_assign_aux
void vector<T>::_M_assign_aux(FI first, FI last,std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
}
```

Comment: yeah, that is from vector.tcc actually. Well one more question about g++. What is the difference of stl_vector.h and vector.tcc?

Comment: @JiříLechner .tcc is often used as the extension for implementations of template classes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is a method template for a class template. Therefore, the first `template <typename T>` applies to `vector<T>` (the class template). Then, the `template <typename FI>` applies to the method `_M_assign_aux()`.

If you would gather the whole thing in a unique place it would look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class vector {
    // Some stuff
    template <typename FI>
    void _M_assign_aux(FI first, FI last, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
        // Some impl
    }
};
```